# New to Xamarinn possible to Drag and Drop for the UI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and coding altogether. I was wondering can i drag and drop to create the UI or are there any applications online i can drag and drop then copy the code over?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.  Xamarin Forms does not have any drag-drop design tools.  Most devs layout their UI by coding XAML.

Comment: Is there anywhere online that i can drag and drop then paste the code?